# Print True in the console depending on a Specific Date

Tags: javascript, date, console

I am trying to print `True` in the console when a Specific date comes.

> Here is my code :

```
setInterval(() => {
 if (new Date() == new Date("2022-06-18T06:27:00")) {
   console.log("true");
 } else {
   console.log("false");
 }
}, 1000);
```

But it keeps showing `False`

There is another way to do what I am thinking about?

> Note: Both of `new Date()` and the Date which I have provided in the `Stamp time` are the same on the console

Comment: Are you SURE `2022-06-18T06:27:00` will be an exact match with `new Date()` if the interval is running "only" every seconds? In a `new Date()`, milliseconds are taken in account...........

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette
I have tried to measure it with respect to milliseconds, but it is not working also

Comment: Sure! Because it is a no-can-do (resonnably... some freak will prove me wrong for sure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
setInterval(() => {
 if (new Date().toString() == new Date("2022-06-18T03:32:00").toString()) {
   console.log("true");
 } else {
   console.log("false");
 }
}, 1000);
```

```js
var date = document.getElementById('date')
    var button = document.getElementById('submit')
    var result = document.getElementById('info')
    var reset = document.getElementById('reset')

    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        date.disabled = true
        button.disabled = true
    var Timer = setInterval(() => {
            if (new Date().toString() == new Date(date.value).toString()) {
                result.innerHTML = "The date is: " + new Date().toString() + " Which is the same as the date you entered"
                clearInterval(Timer)
                date.disabled = false
                button.disabled = false
                return;
            }
            result.innerHTML = "Waiting for the date..."
           }, 1000);
    });

    reset.addEventListener('click', () => {
        input.disabled = false
        button.disabled = false
        result.innerHTML = "";
    })
```

```html
<input type="datetime-local" id="date">
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
<p id="info"></p>
```

Comment: Now it is working, But please can you explain why it was not working if I did not convert it to String also the condition `==` is ignoring the data type

Comment: @AliHsaino the reason your `==` didn't work is because the things you are comparing are objects, and objects are equal *only* when they are the same object